# passing a data frame to a function in R language

Tags: r, function

I want to pass a data frame to a function as an argument. And then inside the function, I want to work on different combinations of columns for graphical presentation. Basically, I want to do graphical presentation on different data files. I want that, I pass the data file as an argument and then get the graphs. How can I do this in R.

Comment: not enough detail.  Please give us a more concrete example of what you're trying to do ...

Comment: for example, I have a data frame called "df" and from R console, I want to pass df to a function like \\ > plot_graph(df) and then I have a instructions of functions in a script file where I will make different plots and print

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving us much info but here is a very basic starting point:

```
library(ggplot2) # if you don't have this library run install.packages('ggplot2')

myAmazingFunction <- function(myDF) {
 ggplot(myDF,aes(X,Y))+geom_line()
}

df <-data.frame(X=1:30, Y=runif(30), Z=1.3*runif(30))
myAmazingFunction(df)
```

Comment: if this solves your problem you're encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept the answer